как использовать инструменты, установленные с помощью pip
установил через pip auto-py-to-exe, в установленных видно, что компоненты есть, но при попытке использования в терминале пишет, что такой команды нет 
при попытке запустить приложение также выходит ошибка

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

понял, добавить в виде текста?

Вызывать нужно просто из консоли, а не из PowerShell

как ее открыть в vscode?

https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

в консоли надо было написать это, поскольку было несколько версий питона
python -m auto_py_to_exe

